# Installing Ubuntu 10.04 on a new Windows 8 Asus Laptop

Tags: 10.04, windows, uefi

I need to install Ubuntu 10.04 on a new Asus Windows 8 laptop (s300). I need to do this for a development project which required that specific version.

I have successfully been able to install 12.10 from a USB stick. But if I try the same process using 10.04 it the machine ignores the USB stick even when I am explicitly booting from it and goes straight to booting Windows.

I think it has something to do with EFI / UEFI on newer machines, since any installation guides demand 12.10 as a pre-requisite for EFI systems.

I am not fluent in Linux or Windows 8 and I am stuck.

Is it in anyway possible to accomplish this or am I out of luck?

Any help / advice would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

TJM

Answer (score 0):

just a thought but why not install what you need with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads)?  I would not see why you shouldn't be able to.  You would probably have to check the BIOS for virtual.  Create a shared folder and you can share content.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you think it would get me over the EFI hurdle?

Comment: VirtualBox sets up a complete virtualized PC with its own firmware, which you can set to be either BIOS or EFI. So yes, using VirtualBox will get you over this hurdle. This is likely to be an adequate solution, but if you need access to the computer's "bare" hardware in Linux, it might not be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks. I did install 10.04 using VirtualBox. It worked well enough for me to make some progress, some subsequent stuff I need to install is not fully supported on VirtualBox. However, so I may try Rod Smith's option soon.

Answer (score 0):

If VirtualBox is not sufficient, you should be able to get it working as a direct boot, albeit with some caveats. The most important key to this is to [disable Secure Boot.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/secureboot.html#disable) Unfortunately, different firmware implementations enable you to do this in different ways, so it's hard to advise you about precisely how to do this.

Once Secure Boot is disabled, you might be able to install Ubuntu 10.04 in EFI mode. I don't recall when Ubuntu began including EFI boot support, though, and if 10.04 has it, it's very primitive. Most notably, it will trash your Windows boot loader (as it did until 12.04), so you should back it up by backing up your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) before you install Ubuntu. You'll then be able to restore the backed-up files once you've booted into Ubuntu.

If you can't install Ubuntu 10.04 in EFI mode, you can do it in BIOS mode and then switch to EFI mode by setting up an [EFI boot loader for Linux.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/) GRUB 2 from 2010 had abysmal EFI support, so I recommend staying away from Ubuntu 10.04's offerings on this score unless they've been significantly upgraded. ELILO's probably your best bet.